# Twitter api 1.1 images not showing in feed

Tags: php, api, twitter, social-networking

I have a command that pushes tweets, using the 1.1 version for the twitter API.

It has been working but recently (not entirely sure when), has stopped posting images to twitter.

With extensive debugging there doesn't seem to be any errors at all, but just no images in feed.

Could this be due to changes with the new v2 of the api ?
Has this functionality been deprecated ?

```
public function send($message, $media = null, $options = [])
    {
        $mediaIds = [];
        foreach ((array) $media as $item) {
            $res = $this->request(
                'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json',
                'POST',
                null,
                ['media' => $item]
            );
            $mediaIds[] = $res->media_id_string;
        }
        return $this->request(
            'statuses/update',
            'POST',
            $options + ['status' => $message, 'media_ids' => implode(',', $mediaIds) ?: null]
        );
    }
```

Any ideas gratefully received.

```
mediaIds 
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "xxxxxxxx"
}


 response from media post

 object(stdClass)#1626 (5) {
  ["media_id"]=>
  int(xxxx)
  ["media_id_string"]=>
  string(19) "xxxxx"
  ["size"]=>
  int(129032)
  ["expires_after_secs"]=>
  int(86400)
  ["image"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1623 (3) {
    ["image_type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["w"]=>
    int(400)
    ["h"]=>
    int(400)
  }
}

Successfully posted item to twitter


object(stdClass)#1625 (23) {
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(30) "Thu Dec 02 11:55:42 +0000 2021"
  ["id"]=>
  int(1466375520866775045)
  ["id_str"]=>
  string(19) "1466375520866775045"
  ["text"]=>
  string(20) "New test message 401"
  ["truncated"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["entities"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1624 (4) {
    ["hashtags"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["symbols"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["user_mentions"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["urls"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["source"]=>
  string(67) "<a href="https://www.co-kinetic.com" rel="nofollow">Co-Kinetic </a>"
  ["in_reply_to_status_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["in_reply_to_status_id_str"]=>
  NULL
  ["in_reply_to_user_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["in_reply_to_user_id_str"]=>
  NULL
  ["in_reply_to_screen_name"]=>
  NULL
  ["user"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1621 (43) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(68679793)
    ["id_str"]=>
    string(8) "68679793"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "glen lockhart"
    ["screen_name"]=>
    string(12) "glenlockhart"
    ["location"]=>
    string(14) "Sheffield, UK."
    ["description"]=>
    string(68) "I like tech and burritos and probably other things. Mostly burritos."
    ["url"]=>
    NULL
    ["entities"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1627 (1) {
      ["description"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1628 (1) {
        ["urls"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    ["protected"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["followers_count"]=>
    int(55)
    ["friends_count"]=>
    int(163)
    ["listed_count"]=>
    int(2)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(30) "Tue Aug 25 12:29:11 +0000 2009"
    ["favourites_count"]=>
    int(109)
    ["utc_offset"]=>
    NULL
    ["time_zone"]=>
    NULL
    ["geo_enabled"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["verified"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["statuses_count"]=>
    int(201)
    ["lang"]=>
    NULL
    ["contributors_enabled"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_translator"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_translation_enabled"]=>
```

Comment: What do you get from request

Comment: _"Could this be due to changes with the new v2 of the api ? Has this functionality been deprecated ?"_ - you are still targeting the 1.1 version with your call. And even if anything got deprecated, that would usually affect the new API version only then, making _breaking_ changes within an existing API version, is something that should rather not happen to begin with.

Comment: So when you dump the content of `$mediaIds` after the foreach loop, does that look like it should?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Media upload response looks like this:


```
object(stdClass)#1626 (5) {
  ["media_id"]=>
  int(1466371341519663105)
  ["media_id_string"]=>
  string(19) "1466371341519663105"
  ["size"]=>
  int(129032)
  ["expires_after_secs"]=>
  int(86400)
  ["image"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1623 (3) {
    ["image_type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["w"]=>
    int(400)
    ["h"]=>
    int(400)
  }
}


So, we are thinking Twitter 1.1 hasn't changed anything around the 
https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json recently ?

Comment: I can confirm that there have been no changes to the `/1.1/media/upload` API endpoint recently. This should still work exactly as it has in the past. You are getting back a `media_id_string` which is what should happen.

Comment: Thanks Andy, 
So I guess the problem is attaching the media_id_string to the main post ?
I'll see if I can dump the post and see what that gleens.

Comment: My request object dump:
 
[10002]=>  string(48) "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
  [42]=>  bool(false)
  [19913]=>  bool(true)
  [10023]=>  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Expect:"
    [1]=>
    string(314) "Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0",oauth_nonce="xxxxxxx",oauth_timestamp="1638447828",oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxx",oauth_token="68679793-xxxxxxxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="xxxxx""
  }
.....
  array(2) {
    ["status"]=>    string(21) " New test message 410"
    ["media_ids"]=>    string(19) "1466382591766970375"
  }

Comment: So, it was an issue with the library.

The gd by phpfashion.com/twitter-for-php

This mentions the issue. 
https://twittercommunity.com/t/media-image-doesnt-appear-on-tweet/143780/9


Link from answer (by Andy piper, thanks again Andy ;-) )
https://github.com/dg/twitter-php/pull/72

You can see the code in the repo.

TLDR;

Replace this:

 } elseif ($method === 'GET' && $data) {

with:

} elseif (($method === 'GET' || $method === 'POST') && $data) {


In short, it never worked.

Answer (score 3):

So, it was an issue with the library.

The gd by [phpfashion.com/twitter-for-php](https://phpfashion.com/twitter-for-php).
This mentions the issue.

[twittercommunity.com/t/media-image-doesnt-appear-on-tweet/](http://twittercommunity.com/t/media-image-doesnt-appear-on-tweet/)

Link from answer (by Andy piper, thanks again Andy ;-) )

[github.com/dg/twitter-php/pull/72](https://github.com/dg/twitter-php/pull/72)

You can see the code in the repo, for the main twitter files around link 301

TLDR; Replace this:

```
} elseif ($method === 'GET' && $data) {
```

with:

```
} elseif (($method === 'GET' || $method === 'POST') && $data) {
```

In short, it never worked.

Comment: code change is in 
In the dg/twitter-php/src/Twitter.php

Comment: Hey! Can you please structure your answer in better way? that way it would help other users to better understand your answer in case they are stuck on the issue. Thanks! Keep contributing :)

Comment: I have added a few links and a bit of formatting, not sure what else you were after.
Hope it helps